# Android fingerprint issue on OnePlus 3 (capacity button)

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-security, android-fingerprint-api

I have implemented fingerprint login to my app according to Google Developer sample. 
Now I found that the fingerprint sensor on OnePlus 3 is placed on the home button that is, opposite to other phones, touch button (not clicky one). So when the user tries to login with his fingerprint, he touch the home button, the app goes to the background instead of read fingerprint and login into the app.

I'm curious, if I missed some step that is handling this situation, or if there have to be some workaround to fix this issue?

I'm using this library [RxFingerprint](https://github.com/Mauin/RxFingerprint)

EDIT:

One of my friend tried my FP login on his OP3 and it worked flawlessly. But other users are complaining that it is suspending the app.

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize the fingerprint reader, it will intercept the "home" button click when trying to read the fingerprint, so it won't shut down the app.

The underlying Fingerprint API handles this. I've implemented this in a few apps, completely standard behavior, and i literally have a OnePlus 3 myself, and it works fine.

You need to show us some code to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Thanks for info, that it should work correctly. I'm using library called RxFingerprint.

Comment: @Sandak yes, when you are in need to have fingerprint, keep fingerprint reader initialized so that home button click will not take effect